# getSearchableInfo() returns null

Tags: java, android, xml, searchview, android-appbarlayout

My 4th day trying to figure this out :( I'm trying to add a search ability to my app bar. In process, I need to get `searchManager.getSearchableInfo()` but it returns null, therefore I can't get my search to work. I know there are similar questions, but none works yet.

I desperately need your help!

Summary:

- Activity I want to search FROM: ListActivity (extends
  AppCompatActivity)
- Activity I'm handling the search: SearchResultsActivity (extends ListActivity)
- For app bar, I'm using support library one. This loads correctly, I don't have any issues with other menu items. Here's the code:

  > toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.list_toolbar);
  >       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="etchee.com.weightlifty">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".Search.SearchResultsActivity">

        </meta-data>

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".data.DBviewer" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Search.SearchResultsActivity"
            android:label="@string/input_event"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>



        <activity android:name=".Activity.ListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".Search.SearchResultsActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name=".Search.SuggestionProvider"
            android:authorities="suggestionProviderAuthority"
            android:syncable="false" />

        <activity android:name=".Activity.EditEventActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity.ChooseEventActivity" />

        <provider
            android:name=".data.DataProvider"
            android:authorities="etchee.com.weightlifty"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Option-Related codes, from `ListActivity.java`:**

```
    private void deleteOptionRed(Menu menu) {
        //set delete menu text to red color
        MenuItem delete_all_events = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_delete_all_events);
        SpannableString string = new SpannableString(delete_all_events.getTitle());
        string.setSpan(
                new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(ListActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary)),
                0,
                string.length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_PRIORITY);

        delete_all_events.setTitle(string);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        deleteOptionRed(menu);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    /**
     *  When creating the option, define the searchView. 
     * @param menu menu layout
     * @return  true
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list, menu);

        searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search_button).getActionView();

        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), ListActivity.class);

        //checking logger
        if (searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName) == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(TAG + ": getSearchableInfo() returns null. " +
                    "Cannot start search");
        }

        //Get searchableInfo Object created from the searchable.xml config file
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName));
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_search_button:
//                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
//                intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "Test");
                onSearchRequested();
//                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.menu_delete_all_events:
                int numOfDeletedRows = deleteEventTable();
                Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, String.valueOf(numOfDeletedRows) + " deleted.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_insert_event:
                event_insertDummyValues();
                break;

            case R.id.menu_view_tables:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DBviewer.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

menu_list, used in ListActivity to get menu resource from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search_button"
    android:title="@string/search_events"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_list"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

<item
    android:title="@string/insert_event_values"
    android:id="@+id/menu_insert_event"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    />

<item android:title="@string/view_tables"
    android:id="@+id/menu_view_tables"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:title="@string/delete_all_events"
    android:id="@+id/menu_delete_all_events"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

and lastly, my **searchable.xml config file**. (It's under res/xml. I've made sure.)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/hint_search_events"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="@string/suggestion_provider_authority"
    >
</searchable>
```

Comment: Isn't this the old fashioned way?

Comment: @Eenvincible um, what is the new way?

Comment: Lemme answer this question below

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Create a menu** search_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

**Inflate this menu in your list activity**

The activity class :

```
`implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`
```

Then:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(item);

    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_orders));

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    if (newText.equals("")){
        initProductCatalog();
        return true;
    }else{
        final List<ProductItemObject> filteredModelList = filter(productItemObjects, newText);

        itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
        itemsAdapter.animateTo(filteredModelList);
        mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
        return true;
    }
}

private List<ProductItemObject> filter(List<ProductItemObject> models, String query) {

    query = query.toLowerCase();

    final List<ProductItemObject> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();

    if(query.equals("")) { return productItemObjects; }

    for (ProductItemObject model : models) {
        final String text = model.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(model);
        }
    }
    return filteredModelList;
}
```

Now, your adapter is where the magic happens:

Remember to replace the variable components with your own. I am using RecyclerViewer here too, not the old list views:

**The adapter**

```
public class ProductItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductViewHolder>{

private List<ProductItemObject> products;
private Context context;

public ProductItemsAdapter(List<ProductItemObject> products, Context context) {
    this.products = products;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_catalog_card, parent, false);

    return new ProductViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(products.get(position).getName());
    holder.prices.setText(products.get(position).getPrice());

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(products.get(position).getUrl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.fry_mate_cooking)
            .centerCrop()
            .resize(100, 100)
            .error(R.drawable.product_sample)
            .into(holder.image);
}

public ProductItemObject get(int position){
    return products.get(position);
}

public void remove(int position){
    products.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return products.size();
}

public ProductItemObject getItem(int position){
    return products.get(position);
}

public void setModels(List<ProductItemObject> orders){
    products = new ArrayList<>(orders);
}

public void animateTo(List<ProductItemObject> models) {
    applyAndAnimateRemovals(models);
    applyAndAnimateAdditions(models);
    applyAndAnimateMovedItems(models);
}

private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(List<ProductItemObject> newModels) {
    for (int i = products.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final ProductItemObject model = products.get(i);
        if (!newModels.contains(model)) {
            removeItem(i);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(List<ProductItemObject> newModels) {
    for (int i = 0, count = newModels.size(); i < count; i++) {
        final ProductItemObject model = newModels.get(i);
        if (!products.contains(model)) {
            addItem(i, model);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(List<ProductItemObject> newModels) {
    for (int toPosition = newModels.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
        final ProductItemObject model = newModels.get(toPosition);
        final int fromPosition = products.indexOf(model);
        if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
            moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }
    }
 }

 private ProductItemObject removeItem(int position) {
    final ProductItemObject model = products.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    return model;
 }

 private void addItem(int position, ProductItemObject model) {
    products.add(position, model);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
 }

  private void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    final ProductItemObject model = products.remove(fromPosition);
    products.add(toPosition, model);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
  }
}
```

**Create your viewholder as usual**

```
public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

  @BindView(R.id.product_image)
  CircleImageView image;

  @BindView(R.id.product_name)
  SalesLifeTextView name;

  @BindView(R.id.price)
  SalesLifeTextView prices;

  @BindView(R.id.buy)
  CircleImageView buy;

  public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
  }
}
```

Finally, create a java class (`POJO`) to represent **ProductItemObject** in my case.

This code will enable you to simply search for items in your list using the action bar search icon.

This is alot of code but once you get it working you will be glad you did!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. This is for placing the results in the same activity as a recyclerView, correct?